# Maven web project does not start

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, wildfly, wildfly-8

After converting eclipse web project to maven web project it was not resolve some dependensies.

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Missing artifact
>   org.infinispan:infinispan-core:jar:4.2.1.FINAL    pom.xml /Visual
>   Expressions   line 2  Maven Dependency Problem
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Missing artifact
>   xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1.jbossorg-2  pom.xml /Visual Expressions line
>   2 Maven Dependency Problem

Then I put in pom.xml this and eclipse shows no errors.

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
            <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
            <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

But project failed to start.

```
Failed to start service
        Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-000075: Normal scoped managed bean implementation class has a public field:  [EnhancedAnnotatedFieldImpl] public org.jboss.resteasy.core.AcceptHeaderByFileSuffixFilter.languageMappings"}}
    ...    
    06:30:56,796 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
    06:30:56,796 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
    06:30:56,796 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: WildFly 8.0.0.Final "WildFly" started (with errors) in 10500ms - Started 500 of 735 services (181 services failed or missing dependencies, 90 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
    06:30:56,953 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS016009: Stopping weld service for deployment Visual Expressions.war
    06:30:57,234 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment Visual Expressions.war (runtime-name: Visual Expressions.war) in 303ms
    06:30:57,390 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018558: Undeployed "Visual Expressions.war" (runtime-name: "Visual Expressions.war")
    06:30:57,421 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
    JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Visual Expressions.war".WeldBootstrapService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Visual Expressions.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.xml.ParamTag".WeldInstantiator, service jboss.deployment.unit."Visual Expressions.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.xml.ExprTag".WeldInstantiator, service jboss.deployment.unit."Visual Expressions.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.xml.TransformTag".WeldInstantiator, service jboss.deployment.unit."Visual Expressions.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ParamTag".WeldInstantiator, JBAS014799: ... and 88 more ] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Visual Expressions.war".WeldStartService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Visual Expressions.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.xml.ParamTag".WeldInstantiator, service jboss.deployment.unit."Visual Expressions.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.xml.ExprTag".WeldInstantiator, service jboss.deployment.unit."Visual Expressions.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.xml.TransformTag".WeldInstantiator, service jboss.deployment.unit."Visual Expressions.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ParamTag".WeldInstantiator, JBAS014799: ... and 86 more ] 
          ...............
    JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."Visual Expressions.war".WeldStartService
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: See if http://nickhumphreyit.blogspot.com/2012/03/weld-000075-normal-scoped-managed-bean.html helps and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179825/public-field-in-java

Comment: There are no public fileds in beans. The project worked befor conversion to maven based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the POM was adding a whole bunch of stuff that I thought I needed, but in actuality didn't. I got rid of everything except those I added when the project was't maven based and I added server runtime libraries then everything was cool.

Comment: I had the same problem and I'm on wildfly as well. Did you right click on the project and configure to maven ? Any idea why all those dependencies were added ?

Comment: Same problem when converting dynamic web project to maven project in eclipse. I removed all dependencies except those needed and problem was solved.